# an integer linear programing

Tags: optimization

I want to know if I have an integer variable that I want to use in an ILP. How can I
express the constraint “v = 0 or v = 2” by linear constraints? The main
problem is to forbid the intermediate value 1 without explicitly saying “or”.

any one knows?

Comment: Please give us more details and better description of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use binary integer programming (v in {0,1}) and then substitute v=2v in your objective function.